# eBay API GetOrdersRequest not showing Items awaiting Payment

Tags: php, ebay-api

Here is the XML I'm calling into ebay. I get all completed items except for those completed without a payment (which I've read I should be getting back).

I'd much rather have a method that only calls "Awaiting Payment", "Awaiting Shipping", "Shipped". If that is possible, I'm not aware of it from my research. I'm currently gathering all Completed for *n* days and filtering them out myself

Endpoint:

```
https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
```

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'>
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$requestToken</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
<Pagination>
<EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$page</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
<NumberOfDays>7</NumberOfDays>
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<Version>823</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

Logic on sorting out:

```
foreach($orderArray as $order)
  {
    $paidTime = (isset($order['PaidTime']) ? $order['PaidTime'] : '');
    $shippedTime = (isset($order['ShippedTime']) ? $order['ShippedTime'] : '');
    if($paidTime != "" ){
      if($shippedTime == "")
        array_push($itemPaidNotShipped,$order);
      else
        array_push($itemPaidShipped,$order);
    }else{
      array_push($itemNotPaidNotShipped,$order);
    }
  }
```

---

Edit after accepted Answer, here is my sorting logic:

```
foreach($orderArray as $order){
    $paidTime = (isset($order['PaidTime']) ? $order['PaidTime'] : '');
    $shippedTime = (isset($order['ShippedTime']) ? $order['ShippedTime'] : '');
    $orderStatus = (isset($order['OrderStatus']) ? $order['OrderStatus'] : '');
    if($orderStatus != "" && $orderStatus != 'Cancelled'){
      if($paidTime != "" ){
        if($shippedTime == "")
          array_push($itemPaidNotShipped,$order);
        else
          array_push($itemPaidShipped,$order);
      }else{
        array_push($itemNotPaidNotShipped,$order);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: the question is, the documentation says I should be getting AwaitingPayment back and I'm not. So either what am I doing wrong, or how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe OrderStatus of Completed returns paid orders. You can leave out OrderStatus to receive all orders regardless of status or request Active to get unpaid orders.

If you are a Selling Manager Pro subscriber, you can use the GetSellingManagerSoldListings call

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html

It has a filter field

```
<Filter> SellingManagerSoldListingsPropertyTypeCodeType </Filter>
```

You can find the values here

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/extra/GtSllngMngrSldLstngsRqst.Fltr.html

I use the GetOrders call; the GetSellingManagerSoldListings call includes the following:

Note: This call is subject to change without notice; the deprecation process is inapplicable to this call.

Comment: That was it, it also now gives back Cancelled. So I'm just going to filter those out (since I don't need them). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a call that would only return a specific status like awaiting payment, awaiting shipment, or shipped that I have been able to find. It sounds like you are going in the right direction by gathering the past 7 days and then trying to determine paid status from there.

In order to determine paid status you need to check for PaidTime which can be an element in one of 2 places. The first is order (OrderArray.Order.PaidTime) and the second is transaction (OrderArray.Order.TransactionArray.Transaction.PaidTime). PaidTime is conditionally returned which means if it is not paid it will not be returned. If you parse for PaidTime and it is not present / not returned or is returned and there is no value present the item is considered not paid / awaiting payment. If there is a time present the payment has been received and would be considered paid.

Comment: I'm not getting back those entries at all with my query. My filtering would throw them in "else" if I was, and I'm not seeing them anywhere.